# Does IBM use Dojo Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I was told IBM no-longer uses Dojo. Is this true? A small amount of web searching shows IBM is/was a member of the Dojo Foundation and is/was a code contributor... If it is true, approximately when did IBM stop using Dojo? If its not, to what extend is IBM still actively using and promoting the toolkit (use in their public web sites, product integration/bundling, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/timeline, I recognize names of IBMers: Bill, Peller, DouHays, ...

But you're right: Dojo+Domino (aka Dojomino) seems to be stopped...

Interesting question!

Answer (score 7):

*Disclosure: I am not an IBMer, but I am a Dojo Committer.*

If IBM dropped Dojo, they do a good job hiding it. ;-) If anything, their rate of contributions sharply increased in the last year and continues to grow. Just in time for Dojo 1.5 I fielded at least a dozen IBM contributions to Charting. One of the major new features in 1.5 will be new Claro theme for widgets — developed and contributed by IBM.

A number of contributors and committers are employed by IBM, some of them were hired because they are Dojo experts. As far as I can tell (I am not privy to any IBM secrets) their jobs are still secure.

In any case, while IBM is probably the biggest sponsor of Dojo, it is not in the driver position, and Dojo can survive without their help. While sponsorship is nice and always appreciated, the main driving force behind Dojo is passionate programmers rather then corporations.

To sum it up: do not worry about IBM's position.

Comment: For me and I would assume a good portion of others, IBM backing Dojo lends weight to the fact that it will become the front-end toolkit for the enterprise AKA Java shops. What I would really like to know is whether Oracle will pick up Sun's backing of Dojo, which would all but guarantee it's place in the enterprise.

Comment: IBM is here. Regarding Oracle... They still don't know what to do with Sun's legacy so we have to wait and see. I wish I had a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

Timothy.

Yes, IBM actively uses and supports Dojo.

Don't ask why I know this. ;)

Answer (score 4):

IBM's latest product offerings use dojo (Rational Team Concert / Jazz). I believe they are trying to move towards jDojo now though to help overcome refactoring barriers they have encountered.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post but came up with a high rank in Google. As of this date and going forward, IBM is still serious about Dojo. It has strong client support in WebSphere Application Server. It is now standardized internally with the IBM One UI IDX Toolkit for its own websites. Dojo has a growing footprint in the client components of many of its products. IBM remains a significant contributor.

Answer (score 2):

IBM's main website uses jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: That's perhaps why I was told what I was told. That is interesting, though. They are supporters of it, but not users of it? That's rather convenient.

Comment: Timothy, IBM uses Dojo quite a bit in its products.

Comment: jQuery is used in some of the header and footer for the social share bar, etc. IBM eats their own dog food when it comes to Dojo and use it extensively in their products, as well as on their web site. Remember IBM.com has years of development and some items are older than others, as well they have a lot of third party providers that may provide widgets to them as finished components (that require jQuery).

Comment: that's where jquery belongs - on brochure/front end trivial websites. Dojo is for web applications, where more serious architecture/frameworks are required.  However these days it's more likely to be something else ;)

Answer (score 2):

@Ehsan, you put your finger on one of the biggest misconceptions in this field. Most companies' website has a separate team and set of requirements for their website. It has no relationship typically to the products the organization develops and ships, and the libraries and frameworks they choose to help them do that.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ibm.com/social/impact

Answer (score 1):

IBM is a very large development organization with 5 separate and distinct software brands and many many products in each so to ask whether the entire organization still uses Dojo or not may a bit misleading. It could be the case that a certain team or product has stopped using Dojo but I can definitely tell you many still do. Aside from still being listed as a Dojo sponsor and contributor on the Dojo Foundation's website:  there are active and very recent developments going on around Dojo.

One very interesting thing is JDojo, essentially a translator that lets you write Dojo in Java that then gets translated thus giving you strong typing and Eclipse IDE features. You can check out its wiki page here: https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/JDojo (registration required) or google some blog posts or twitter (can't post links yet on this account)